# Character on :before sometimes displays incorrectly…

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a character applied to a `:before` that *sometimes* doesn't display correctly in Chrome. I can't quite work out the trigger, but I've found that opening the console and refreshing (while the console is still open) seems to get the character back again. However even after closing the console and coming back later it works fine - and then at some point later I'll notice that it's reverted back to this unusual character - but as I say I haven't noticed what triggers it, if anything. A standard refresh without interacting with the console doesn't resolve it.

**How it's supposed to look:**

[image]

**How it sometimes looks:**

[image]

As you can see the character is wrong in the console style preview, as well as on the rendered page (but the CSS is unchanged, and states: `content '“'` (that's a copy and paste with the actual character, by the way).

(I have tested the page in other browsers, and it looks fine, but as I don't know what triggers it I'm not sure that's relevant).

The only place I've ever seen an issue like this is with editing code directly in Bitbucket, on save many characters turn into these strange little glyphs. But that isn't the issue here.

I've double checked and I'm declaring the charset on all pages: `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've now seen this issue on two sites I'm working on locally - with very different codebases. The only commonalities are the fact that it's on a `:before` pseudo element and running in Chrome.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you tried with the CSS value of the character you want? Like `content: '\201C'` in you case.

Comment: Hi Paulie - without knowing what's causing the problem how do I know what code I need to provide to demonstrate the issue? As far as I'm aware I've included all the relevant code. If I have to go and try and get this issue to crop up in jsfiddle then quite frankly I'll just delete the question, as that could take all afternoon, given that I don't know what causes it… (I understand why you're asking, but really I was hoping someone would know what the issue is by the description of the behaviour)

Comment: Hi Pipo - I guess that's a sensible change either way - I'll do that now and monitor.

Comment: Possibly too early to say for sure - but @Pipo that seems to have resolved the issue. So I'm guessing it's an issue with Chrome interpreting that character - it may also have something to do with the pseudo element - but I'd have to set up proper test to work that one out… maybe save that for a rainy day :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked ;)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unicode `content: '\201c';`.

Comment: I think that ultimately this is the solution. I'm still not sure why Chrome sometimes misinterprets it… but either way this does fix it (@Pipo mentioned this solution in the comments).